# 301 redirect with .htaccess from folder to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect all my url to root from sub folder :

```
http://www.example.com/blabla/some-url
to
http://www.example.com/some-url
```

my .htaccess code is :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/blabla$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

but not work for me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching against the wrong parameter.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blabla/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RedirectMatch directive

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/(.+)$ http://example.com/$1
```

This will 301 redirect **/folder/foobar** to **/foobar**